# What series expansions of functions other than Taylor/MacLaurin and Fourier exist?

Tags: functional-analysis, power-series, taylor-expansion, fourier-series

I'm wondering what series expansions exist for functions other than Taylor/MacLaurin and Fourier. I'm even more interested if there exists something in between, which use polynomials like Taylor (eventually wrapped in absolute values) but can approximate functions that are $C^0$ but not $C^1$, like Fourier (or even discontinuous functions altogether).

All other series expansions (or even things like step-function approximation in measure theory) are interesting to me in any case.

Comment: You can look up Laurent series, asymptotic power series, series in terms of orthogonal polynomials (Chebyshev series for example), factorial series.

Comment: Also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pad%C3%A9_approximant

Comment: @Gary Don't forget about Puiseaux series!

Comment: Thank you all !! You've given me a lot to dig. :)

Comment: In addition to normal Fourier series there are Fourier Bessel series (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier%E2%80%93Bessel_series and https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Fourier-BesselSeries.html) which are normally used as an expansion to approximate a function in the interval $(0,1)$, but some functions can also be approximated in the interval $(1,\infty)$ (e.g. $\log(x)=-\log(1/x)$).

Comment: There are also Fourier Mellin series used to approximate recurrent functions for which $f(x)=f(e^{2\pi} x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}_+$ and c-recurrent functions for which $f(x)=e^{2\pi c} f(e^{2\pi c} x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}_+$ (see https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0898122100001395).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be interested in the Wavelet transform and corresponding series expansions. Yves Meyer has a good book about Wavelets. There is, of course, lots of information online about them. You can construct a Hilbert basis for $L^2$ with Wavelets, so smoothness isn't required.

Wiener's chaos expansion is also interesting and useful in stochastic analysis.

Comment: Thank you very much, in addition to your comment, I think you deserve the answer. I'm not sure any specifically will suit my exact needs, but the rabbit hole is enough to give me ideas and different perspectives on my problem.

Comment: @TristanDuquesne I can't take credit for the comment. I don't encounter many other Gary's, so this is a bit of a coincidence.

Comment: Oh, hahaha, didn't notice that. Sorry, Gary not-Moon !